# Atualizar um valor dentro de uma função

Tags: python, funções

Estou iniciando no Python e preciso de ajuda para criar a seguinte função:

```
ESQUERDA = -1
DIREITA = 1
CANHAO = 'A'
EXPLOSAO = '*'

def moveCanhao(direcao, matriz):
''' int, (matriz) -> bool

      Recebe um inteiro com a direção (valores definidos em ESQUERDA e
      DIREITA) para mover o canhão do jogador (caracter definido em CANHAO)
      e a matriz de caracteres do jogo, para mover o canhão nessa direção.
      Ao mover tem que observar se atingiu algum laser de alguma nave (caso
      no qual tem que imprimir um EXPLOSAO no lugar). Nesse caso precisará
      informar que o canhão foi atingido pois a função retorna esse valor.

      Retorna:

      True se canhão do jogador foi atingido (False se não)

      Obs.: o movimento do canhão é ciclíco quando ele se move além dos
      limites laterais da matriz do jogo.'''
```

A matriz do jogo tem 20 linhas e 57 colunas. O canhao deve estar sempre na última linha e a cada iteração do usuário (digitando esquerda ou direita) o canhão deve ser mover.

O que eu já fiz:

```
v = False
k = 28
n = k + direcao
matriz[19][n % 57] = CANHAO
if direcao == DIREITA:
    matriz[19][n - 1] = " "
else:
    matriz[19][n + 1] = " "
k += direcao

return v
```

A função só deve retornar True ou False (determinado pela variável v). O grande problema e a minha dúvida entram na atualização da variável k:
Eu preciso que k inicie de 28 e cada vez que a função for chamada o k atualize para "k+direcao". Porém, a cada vez que a função é chamada o k se atualiza para 28 e o acumulador no final da função se torna inútil. 
Um detalhe importante é que não é permitido utilizar imports, bibliotecas ou funções mais específicas. Tem que ser bem rústico mesmo.
Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você já percebeu, fazer `k = 28` no início da função vai fazer com que o valor 28 seja atribuído a `k` sempre que a função seja executada. Então como fazer com que isso não aconteça? É só não fazer `k = 28` dentro da função.

Como esse vai ser seu valor inicial, você tem que atribuí-lo no começo do programa. Por exemplo, junto com a declaração de suas outras variáveis:

```
ESQUERDA = -1
DIREITA = 1
CANHAO = 'A'
EXPLOSAO = '*'
k = 28
```

Então, para modificá-la dentro da função, você só tem que fazer `global k` pra dizer pro programa que está se referindo à variável `k` do escopo global do programa, e não quer criar uma nova variável `k` dentro do escopo local da função:

```
def moveCanhao(direcao, matriz):
    global k
    v = False
    n = k + direcao
    matriz[19][n % 57] = CANHAO
    if direcao == DIREITA:
        matriz[19][n - 1] = " "
    else:
        matriz[19][n + 1] = " "
    k += direcao

    return v
```

Comment: Deu certo mano!!!! Obrigadão! salvou meu semestre hahah

Comment: @PYTHON_13 de nada, fico feliz por ajudar! Se a resposta resolveu o problema, não esqueça de aceitá-la pra marcar a questão como resolvida :)